# Testing achivements in non (yet)  published game

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I have a little game with achievements support. The game has not been published yet, but I need to test achievements. I can do it now but just partially, for example when I execute game center application  it seems it allways run in sandbox mode and this game is not listed in the Games tab. So, I can't see if the achievement achieved where ok or not. Is there any way to check this information for a wip in progress game?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check that by presenting the standard achievements interface, that will show you all the achievements defined for the game that are not hidden and which ones have been completed by the current logged in user. You should put something similar to this on your ViewController and invoke it as the target of a button for example:

```
- (void)showAchievements{
  GKAchievementViewController *achievements = [[GKAchievementViewController alloc] init];
  if (achievements != nil){
    achievements.achievementDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController: achievements animated: YES];
  }
 [achievements release];
}
```

Your ViewController should implement the GKAchievementViewControllerDelegate protocol.